# SQL Returning a datetime from a procedure results in Implicit conversion error

Tags: sql

I'm fairly new to SQL and was trying to write a procedure that would check a passed in value and set a local datetime variable and then return that variable.

```
USE [MyDB]

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [Common].[Update_Date] 
@Status_ID int
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Date_Value DATETIME

IF @Status_ID = 2
    SET @Date_Value = GETDATE()
ELSE
    SET @Date_Value = NULL

RETURN @Date_Value
END
GO
```

When I try to execute this script I get the following error:

Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Procedure Update_Date, Line 19
Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Is it trying to do something with my @Status_ID parameter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stored procedures return values by using OUTPUT parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Common].[Update_Date] 
@Status_ID int,
@Date_Value DATETIME OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF @Status_ID = 2
    SET @Date_Value = GETDATE()
ELSE
    SET @Date_Value = NULL
END
GO
```

When invoked from ADO.Net, you use [`ParameterDirection.Output`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.parameterdirection.aspx). From T-SQL you invoke with an OUTPUT clause:

```
declare @date DATETIME;
exec  [Common].[Update_Date] 2, @date OUTPUT;
SELECT @date;
```

In general is better not to mix procedure output with the return and with the result set (so that would be a vote against most other recommendation you got to use `SELECT`). Using OUTPUT makes procedures reusable from other T-SQL code, using result set (SELECT) makes it much harder to use as T-SQL has problems capturing the result set of an invoked procedure (you'd have to use INSERT ... SELECT and deal with [all the problems *that* has](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#INSERTEXEC)).

Comment: Note the `OUTPUT` in the call `exec [Common].[Update_Date] 2, @date OUTPUT;`. Without it, `@date` remains uninitialized. Just learned it the hard way.

Answer (score 3):

`RETURN` values in Stored Procedures can only be integers. Therefore youre getting an error converting `@Date_Value` to an `int`

It looks like you need a Function, not a Stored Procedure

[CREATE FUNCTION (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx)

Alternatively, you can change `RETURN` to `SELECT`, but I would recommend using a `FUNCTION` for this type of request.

Comment: What is the deciding factor in choosing to make this a function over a procedure?

Comment: In general I see a Stored Procedure as being an action which will change data stored in the database, or return an entire result set, and optionally OUTPUT parameter values. Whereas a Function doesn't affect any data, and simply returns a value based on parameters passed and optionally data read

Answer (score 2):

The return value from a stored procedure must be an integer.  The `RETURN @Date_Value` line is throwing the error.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the return value of a stored procedure is an integer, and your return statement is converting the datetime to int.  Can you do a select instead to return the value?

```
SELECT @Date_Value
```

Here is a link on return values, output values, and result sets that you might find useful:

http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Stored_Procedures_-_Output_Parameters_%26_Return_Values

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use "return" to return a value, you use "select" to return the value. Just change the RETURN keyword at the end of your SP and use SELECT and i will work.

Answer (score 0):

The Return keyword must be used to return an integer. Try changing it to Select @Date_Value

Answer (score 0):

You had a few problems. Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Common].[Update_Date](
   @Status_ID INT
) AS

SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN 

   --will @Date_Value have an initial value of NULL????
   DECLARE @Date_Value DATETIME       

   SET @Date_Value = NULL

   IF @Status_ID = 2 BEGIN
      SET @Date_Value = GETDATE()
   END

   SELECT @Date_Value

END
```